# How can I add mutiple anchors to the same block?

Tags: asciidoctor

I'm using AsciiDoctor to create an HTML manual. In order to keep existing links valid, I need multiple anchors at the same header.

Basically I want this output:

```html
<a id="historic1"></a>
<a id="historic2"></a>
<h2 id="current">Caption</h2>
```

While it is possible to create multiple inline anchors like this

```markdown
Inline [[historic1]] [[historic2]] [[current]] Anchor
```

```html
Inline <a id="historic1"></a> <a id="historic2"></a> <a id="current"></a> Anchor
```

it looks like additional anchor macros in front of blocks are simply swallowed:

```markdown
[[historic1]]
[[historic2]]
[[current]]
== Caption
```

```html
<h2 id="current">Caption</h2>
```

So what are my options to have multiple anchors in front of a block?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the shorthand version of this solution.

```
[#current]
== [[historic1]][[historic2]]Caption
```

Now you get all three anchors on the same heading.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do (tested with Asciidoctor.js 1.5.4):

```
== anchor:historic1[historic1] anchor:historic2[historic2] anchor:current[current] Caption

Some text
```

Output:

```
<h2 id="__a_id_historic1_a_a_id_historic2_a_a_id_current_a_caption"><a id="historic1"></a> <a id="historic2"></a> <a id="current"></a> Caption</h2>
<div class="sectionbody">
<div class="paragraph">
<p>Some text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

There are two issues:

- [#840](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/840)
- [#1689](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1689)

Comment: Deleting this answer as the editing window is totally messed up.

Comment: That works indeed, but unfortunately the anchors are duplicated in the toc, resulting in duplicate ids.

Comment: The problem with the toc is a separate and open issue. See https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/840

Comment: I have documented the bug I mean on the Asciidoctor ML: http://discuss.asciidoctor.org/Multiple-anchor-definitions-td4263.html